# How to call ASP.NET function from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, webforms

I am pulling data over json in the load event.

This is what I want to do; I have svg map on my aspx page. I detect the city clicked on the map with javascript.

When the city is clicked, I want to send the city name to the code side and I want to include the code in the form load event into the function.

How can I run the c # function in javascript.

```
protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        {
            string url = "https://url.com/bayi/api/bayiler?tur=ak&il=antalya";

            using (var response = await client.GetAsync(url))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string gelen = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    List<BayiModel> listBayi = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BayiModel>>(gelen);

                    rptBayi.DataSource = listBayi;
                    rptBayi.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can either call webservice or on svc click you can call button click event from javascript code.

Comment: Your problem is the data binding. You can call the url from jQuery (`$.get`, `$.ajax` etc) and have the json data returned to your javascript code. Then you need to populate the page with that data *from your javascript code*.